# How do I print only one new line in Python? "\n" does not give me my desired effect

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am well aware of `print("\n")`, but that gives this result in my cmd:

[image]

The first output (with the "raw" lists) continue on to the next line, but using `\n` seems to skip a line. How can I make sure that the `print_pretty` function goes to the next line, instead of skipping a line?

This is my code so far:

```
board = [["#" for i in range(5)] for y in range(5)]

def print_pretty(b):
    for _ in b:
        for __ in _:
            print(__, end="  ")
        print("\n")

print(board)
print_pretty(board)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`print()` *adds* a newline. Just print without arguments:

```
print()
```

or tell it not to add a newline:

```
print('\n', end='')
```

The latter is much more verbose than it needs to be of course.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score -2):

This line print("\n") needs to be under print(__, end="  ") remember the spaces
or add print('\n', end='') to print the new line